# How to save Ansible ad-hoc result to JSON fast?

Tags: ansible

For example,
I have 100 IP, I want to collect their hostnames or product type. I know Saltstack has this feature via a simple `--output=json # or yaml`.

How should I save this result to JSON format even a CSV file fast?

According to [Ansible Callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html), I can edit `ansible.cfg` to use a JSON callback. But can I only use specific callback form time to time? I don't want to use specific callback all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If [`fact_caching`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) is enabled you can according [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html)_module [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#examples) just run something like

```bash
ansible test --ask-pass -m setup --args 'filter=ansible_fqdn'
```

and find via `cat /tmp/ansible/facts_cache/test.example.com` a result like

```yaml
ansible_fqdn: test.example.com
discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
```

depending on your configuration. See [Enabling inventory cache plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#enabling-inventory-cache-plugins) for more information.